# Why when spawning a process in multiprocessing with numpy, it cannot import numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, numpy

I have this problem where when I spawn a process in my python 3.7.4 virtual env, I cannot create a process if I imported pandas.

Minimal code looks like this :

```py
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def f(x):
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    r = p.submit(f, 0)
    print(r.result())
```

pip freeze looks like this :

```py
altgraph==0.17.2
colorama==0.4.4
future==0.18.2
importlib-metadata==4.11.1
loguru==0.6.0
numpy==1.21.5
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.5
pefile==2021.9.3
pydicom==2.2.2
pyinstaller==4.9
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.2
pyparsing==3.0.7
PyQt5==5.15.0
PyQt5-sip==12.9.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
QDarkStyle==3.0.3
QtPy==2.0.1
six==1.16.0
typing-extensions==4.1.1
win32-setctime==1.1.0
XlsxWriter==3.0.2
zipp==3.7.0
```

I get this error :

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't create any threads. It creates a subprocess. Also, please don't post your errors as images.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it's a subprocess ?

Comment: Also: have you googled your error "numpy has no attribute float128"? https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/613

Comment: Yeah I tried. The error you linked seems linked to fast.ai, tabular, PyQtGraph, PyOpenGL, not a single package I use unfortunatly. That's why I am posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: How did you install Numpy? Have you attempted upgrading it?

Comment: At first, it was in requirements.txt, then I deleted it (so it's installed along side pandas), then I tried to force the pandas major version but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Your code works fine on **macOS**. If I run `print(np.finfo(np.float64))` it works, but if I try with `np.float128` I get the same error message as you, i.e. Numpy has no `float128`. My `np.__version__=1.21.4` and `pd.__version__=1.4.1`